# Exposing the current state name with ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-translate

I'm trying to implement a language switcher where if a user clicks on "de" from any given page on an "en" side - it takes them to that page of the "de" side. If I console.dir the $state parameter, it exposes the values I'd want with the "current" property of the given $state. If I try to console.dir the $state.current to focus on the values I want, it only gives the parent state property (my current views are nested).

My current thinking is, I'm on url/en/content, and dynamically I can then have my lang navigation dynamically load the appropriate destination points into some kind of data attribute, pick those up with a custom directive where I'd initiate a "go to" and set my preferedLanguage value per angular-translate.

The key issue at the moment is exposing that $state name - again, when simply browsing $state the current object gives the values I'd want, but $current.state directly only gives the parent state.

If anyone has a better suggestion of how to do this (in a angular way - no custom cookie junk) I'm happy to take suggestions.

Thanks!

Update! CODE SAMPLES:

Object reference of my states:

```
var urlStates = {
        en: {
            home: {
                name: 'home',
                url: '/en',
                templateUrl: 'templates/'+lang+'/home.html',
                abstract: 'true'
            },
            home_highlights: {
                name:'home.highlights',
                url: '',
                templateUrl: 'templates/'+lang+'/home.highlights.html'
            },
            home_social:
            {
                name: 'home.social',
                url: '/social',
                templateUrl: 'templates/'+lang+'/home.social.html'
            },
            home_map:
            {
                name: 'home.map',
                url: '/map',
                templateUrl: 'templates/'+lang+'/home.map.html'
            }

        };
```

My States:

```
$stateProvider
        .state(urlStates.en.home)
        .state(urlStates.en.home_highlights)
        .state(urlStates.en.home_social)
        .state(urlStates.en.home_map);

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

})
```

Controller:

```
.controller('LandingPage', function($translate, $state){
    this.state = $state;
    this.greeting = "Hello";
});
```

And Lastly, the output I see in the dom:

With this.state = $state;

```
{
    "params": {},
    "current": {
        "name": "home.highlights",
        "url": "",
        "templateUrl": "templates/en/home.highlights.html" },
        "transition": null
}
```

With this.state = $state.current

```
{
    "name": "",
    "url": "^",
    "views": null,
    "abstract": true
}
```

Comment: Something's not clear to me. You need to access `$state.$current.name`, but can only see it when you debug in `console`?

Comment: If so, you can keep track of the $state in the $rootScope, and assign a controller to each child state:
`controller: function($rootScope, $scope) { $rootScope.state = $scope.$state; }`

Comment: Thanks for the answers - the problem is that $state (when debugged in the console) shows that "current" property as an object containing the correct properties for the nested view I'm on. However, when I try t console log $state.current.name - which from the previous console log showed the correct value - I only get the name of the parent $state.

Comment: Have a look at `ng-translate` which is specifically made for sites with multiple languages: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate

Answer (score 82, accepted):

this is how I do it

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var module = angular.module('yourModuleName', ['ui.router']);

module.run( ['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
                      function ($rootScope,   $state,   $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams; 
}
]);
```

HTML:

```
<pre id="uiRouterInfo">
      $state = {{$state.current.name}}
      $stateParams = {{$stateParams}}
      $state full url = {{ $state.$current.url.source }}    
</pre>
```

EXAMPLE

http://plnkr.co/edit/LGMZnj?p=preview

Comment: Why do the `$rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams; ` though?

Comment: @ChanandlerBong To make it globally available at any scope.

Comment: It's already globally available by injecting it where it's needed. No need to use $rootScope for it.

Comment: @Angelin If you need to explicitly inject it everywhere you need it, so is not "already globally available" XD.

Answer (score 9):

Answering your question in this format is quite challenging.

On the other hand you ask about navigation and then about current `$state` acting all weird.

For the first I'd say it's too broad question and for the second I'd say... well, you are doing something wrong or missing the obvious :)

Take the following controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
  $scope.state = $state;
});
```

Where `app` is configured as:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
        url: '/main',
        templateUrl: 'main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .state('main.thiscontent', {
        url: '/thiscontent',
        templateUrl: 'this.html',
        controller: 'ThisCtrl'
    })
    .state('main.thatcontent', {
        url: '/thatcontent',
        templateUrl: 'that.html'
    });
});
```

Then simple HTML template having

```
<div>
  {{ state | json }}
</div>
```

Would "print out" e.g. the following

```
{ 
  "params": {}, 
  "current": { 
    "url": "/thatcontent", 
    "templateUrl": "that.html", 
    "name": "main.thatcontent" 
  }, 
  "transition": null
}
```

I put up a small example showing this, using `ui.router` and `pascalprecht.translate` for the menus. I hope you find it useful and figure out what is it you are doing wrong.

Plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/XIW4ZE

*Screencap*

---

[image: imgur]

Comment: "you are doing something wrong or missing the obvious" - a very wise deduction from the state of my question. :) I'm trying to figure this out here. I am updating my answer with some code examples. The problem is, When I pass the $state object to the front end - I see that my ideal value lives at $state.current.name - if I try to access that, say, send that specific value to the front end with $state.value.name I get the name of the parent state not the nested state. But - enough talk, see above again for some code. :)

Answer (score 5):

In my current project the solution looks like this:

I created an abstract Language State

```
$stateProvider.state('language', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/:language',
    template: '<div ui-view class="lang-{{language}}"></div>'
});
```

Every state in the project has to depend on this state

```
$stateProvider.state('language.dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard'
    //....
});
```

The language switch buttons calls a custom function:

```
<a ng-click="footer.setLanguage('de')">de</a>
```

And the corresponding function looks like this (inside a controller of course):

```
this.setLanguage = function(lang) {
    FooterLog.log('switch to language', lang);
    $state.go($state.current, { language: lang }, {
        location: true,
        reload: true,
        inherit: true
    }).then(function() {
        FooterLog.log('transition successfull');
    });
};
```

This works, but there is a nicer solution just changing a value in the state params from html:

```
<a ui-sref="{ language: 'de' }">de</a>
```

Unfortunately this does not work, see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1031

Comment: This now works `<a ui-sref="{ language: 'de' }">de</a>` see: https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/directives.html#uisrefdirective

Answer (score 3):

Use Timeout

```
$timeout(function () { console.log($state.current, 'this is working fine'); }, 100);
```

See - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1627

Comment: You can omit the delay...

`$timeout(function() { console.log($state.current); });`

Answer (score 1):

I wrapped around `$state` around `$timeout` and it worked for me.

For example,

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('BodyController', BodyController);

  BodyController.$inject = ['$state', '$timeout'];

  /* @ngInject */
  function BodyController($state, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function(){
      console.log($state.current);
    });

  }
})();
```

Comment: This only worked for me when I set my timeout to about 500 ms, under 200ms console logs something else like in original question. This seems a fuzzy solution to me, even though it works

Answer (score 0):

Its just because of the load time angular takes to give you the current state.

If you try to get the current state by using `$timeout` function then it will give you correct result in `$state.current.name`

```
$timeout(function(){
    $rootScope.currState = $state.current.name;
})
```