# How can set nested routed with Angularjs loading a view that contains others view inside?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

As I wrote in title, I can't understand how to use nested view. I'm trying to use UI-Router.

Say for example I've the following html:

```
<div ui-view="viewA"></div>
<div ui-view="viewB"></div>
```

I wish to inject two different templates for `"viewA"` and `"viewB"`

JS routes:

```
function configB($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
        .state("/",{
           url: "/",
           templateUrl : "/testingBlock.htm",
           controllerAs : "MainCTRL as ctrl"
        })
        .state("login",{
            url: "/login",
            templateUrl : "/app/templates/login.htm",
            controllerAs : "MainCTRL as ctrl"
        })
        .state("multi",{
            url: "/multi",
            templateUrl : "/app/templates/multipleView.htm",
            controllerAs : "MainCTRL as ctrl"
        });

}
```

HTML for *"/app/templates/multipleView.htm"*:

```
<div ui-view="viewA"></div>
<div ui-view="viewB"></div>
```

Comment: what is your routing setting ? addit please and add your corresponding HTML

Comment: Here, take a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/25372142/1061668

Comment: @MikkoViitala how can that help me? How can I make a STATE point to a named view? Where are in that link nested views?

Comment: Look at the plunker link in the post, same as here http://plnkr.co/edit/XIW4ZE

Comment: I can see nothing useful, sorry. Can you clearly tell me what should I do?

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood your question entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dSCCWoEROLjIZgJGbQgK?p=preview). States defintion would be like this

```
// parent       
.state("multi", {
  url: "/multi",
  views: { 
    '': {
      templateUrl: "app/templates/multipleView.htm",
      controllerAs: "MainCTRL as ctrl",
    },
    'viewA@multi': {
      template: "multi parent content",
    },
    'viewB@multi': {
      templateUrl: "testingBlock.htm",
      controllerAs: "MainCTRL as ctrl",
    },
  }
})
// child
.state("multi.child", {
  url: "/child",
  views: { 
    'viewA': {
      template: "multi child content",
    },
    'viewB': {
      templateUrl: "testingBlock.htm",
      controllerAs: "MainCTRL as ctrl",
    },
  }
});
```

The parent contains the unnamed view '' with a template: 'app/templates/multipleView.htm', which contains our targets

```
<div ui-view="viewA"></div>
<div ui-view="viewB"></div>
```

And also, that **parent** state "multi" fills these targets with other views using absolute naming:

```
    'viewA@multi': {
      template: "multi parent content",
    },
    'viewB@multi': {
      templateUrl: "testingBlock.htm",
      controllerAs: "MainCTRL as ctrl",
    },
```

Child state then just injects into these two parent targets, using relative names

```
views: { 
    'viewA': {
      template: "multi child content",
    },
    'viewB': {
      templateUrl: "testingBlock.htm",
      controllerAs: "MainCTRL as ctrl",
    },
  }
```

Read more here

- [Nested States and Nested Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views)
- [Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

also this:

[View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

> Behind the scenes, every view gets assigned an absolute name that follows a scheme of **`viewname@statename`**, where viewname is the name used in the view directive and state name is the state's absolute name, e.g. contact.item. You can also choose to write your view names in the absolute syntax.

Comment: Great to see that. Enjoy awesome UI-Router ;)