# Show/Hide elements on website for certain pages

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using AngularUI Router to navigate content on my website. I have some webpages that show the header/footer navigation and some that do not. I want to be able to detect what my current page is and insert the HTML for the header/footer if needed.

Here is my current router

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider',
  function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
      })
      .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'partials/about.html',
        controller: 'aboutCtrl'
      })
      .state('contact', {
        url: '/contact',
        templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html',
        controller: 'contactCtrl'
      })
      .state('create', {
        url: '/create',
        templateUrl: 'partials/create.html',
        controller: 'createCtrl'
      })
      .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
      })
}]);
```

For the html I have this

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <body>

    <!-- *********** HEADER ************* -->
    <div ng-include=""></div>

    <!-- ********** CONTENT *********** -->
    <div ui-view></div>

    <!-- **************** FOOTER ****************** -->
    <div ng-include="'partials/standard_footer.html'"></div>

  </body
</html>
```

For the webpages create and login I do not want to show the header and footer, but I am not sure how to do that.

I want to do something like this,

```
<div ng-if="!login && !create" ng-include="'standard_header.html'"></div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expose `$state` on the `$rootScope` and that will make it accessible in your webpage.
You can then simply check for `state.current.name != 'login'`
Like below:
[Exposing the current state name with ui router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25370775/exposing-the-current-state-name-with-ui-router)

Edit:
Working Plunker of what i meant: https://plnkr.co/edit/JDpCo3fTePobuX9Qoxjn

Comment: I am new to angular and can't seem to follow this, can you elaborate?

Comment: I have added a plukr as an e.g.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Just add a flag in the params of the appropriate states:

```
.state('create', {
  url: '/create',
  templateUrl: 'partials/create.html',
  controller: 'createCtrl',
  params: {
    hideHeaderAndFooter: true
  }
})
.state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
  controller: 'loginCtrl',
  params: {
    hideHeaderAndFooter: true
  }
})
```

And then inject the $stateParams service in your controllers. Every property of the params object will be exposed as a property of the object this service returns:

```
loginCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams'] 

function loginCtrl($scope, $stateParams) {
  $scope.hideHeaderAndFooter = $stateParams.hideHeaderAndFooter
}
```

Then you can use ng-if just the way you meant to use it:

```
<div ng-if="!hideHeaderAndFooter" ng-include="'standard_header.html'"></div>
```